# Preparations for iOS app so I can add in-app-purchases later

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, extend

I'm currently developing the "basic" version of an iOS app. At some point in the future I want to add functionality that I want to make available as an in-app purchase. What steps do I have to take to make sure I can extend my app at a later point?

(Note: I'm not looking for tips or a tutorial on how to code in-app-purchases, I just want to make sure that I can add in-app-purchases later.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **MOST** important thing you need to remember if you want to integrate In-App Purchase or APNS is that when you create your app and about to upload it to App Store, **do not** put a wild card character in the bundle identifier.

The general convention followed around the world is **com.yourcompanyname.appname**.

So **do not put a "*"** or any other wild card character after your appname.

This is the single most important thing you need to take care of as of now.

Answer (score 4):

There isn't really anything you need to do in your app to pave the way for IAP *before* actually adding IAP to your app.

What you will need to do:

1.Configure your App ID to enable In App Purchase, (or APNS, Game
    Center, iCloud) through the iOS Provision Portal in the dev center.

2.Then you need to configure the IAP products that you want to
    sell, which is done in iTunes Connect. One thing to note here is
    that once you assign an identifier to a "product" then if for some
    reason you want to start over in iTC, then you can't re-use those
    identifiers.

3.Add functionality to your app.

4.Then create a new version of your app in iTC, make sure the IAP products are "ready
    for sale", and then there is a checkbox when getting your new version approved to request that the IAP stuff is also approved - you need to make sure that stuff is filled in, otherwise the app could get approved, but your IAP stuff won't work.

I think, (but can't confirm as I haven't needed to do this yet) that once you've gone through that IAP process, then you can modify your existing IAP products (such as name or pricing) without needing a new version/approval.

Then you just need to watch the money pour in. Or not. Your milage may vary.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the following incredibly useful.

http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/in-app-purchases-a-full-walkthrough/

http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/invalid-product-ids/

In particular the information returned from failed in app purchases is incredibly useless to the dev. Which is why the second link and its checklist is invaluable.